# If category_ID not present, display only 1 div instead of X amount of categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working with Wordpress and some course-plugin. A course can be canceled (`z_aflyst`), otherwise it should just get a `afholdt` (= course has been held) banner.

However, I'm having some trouble with getting only one `Afholdt` banner. I'm looping through the categories with the following code:

```
foreach ($category_detail as $category_ID)
    {       
        if($category_ID->cat_name == 'z_aflyst') {
        echo "<div class='aflyst_badge_normal'><img src='http://kursus.billetten.dk/wp-content/themes/kurser/img/aflyst.png' width=80/></div>";
    }
    else ($date_start <= time()) {
        echo "<div class='aflyst_badge_normal'><img src='http://kursus.billetten.dk/wp-content/themes/kurser/img/afholdt.png' width=80/></div>";
    }
}
```

It's very logical the result is as following:
[image]
The result is like that, because every course has at least two other categories (you can see that in the `var_dump` above `TMS+ 3`).

**The problem**

The `foreach` is of course looping through all categories and is checking what category it is and outputting either the `if` or `else`, depending on the category. How do I rewrite my `foreach` so it only displays one `Aflyst`-banner when the category `z_aflyst` is present and only one `Afholdt`-banner, when the category `z_aflyst` is NOT present?

I hope my question is clear, as I had trouble putting the problem to words!

Edit: I want to prevent my client to have to select a category whenever a course has been held, so adding a category specifically for that is not a solution (it's what I had in the beginning, but it's not very user friendly. It has to be checked automatically).

Comment: You can use some var before the loop and then do some if inside the loop

Comment: Could you explain me how? Edit: I have also tried `preg_replace` and replace the div (placing the `$date_start <= time()` outside the loop), but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Same solution that Marco has given but I have modified bit :

```
    $i=0; //Take one variable and initially give it value 0

    foreach ($category_detail as $category_ID)
        {       
            if($category_ID->cat_name == 'z_aflyst') {
            if($i == 0): //put one dummy condition to prevent it from echoing again
                echo "<div class='aflyst_badge_normal'><img src='http://kursus.billetten.dk/wp-content/themes/kurser/img/aflyst.png' width=80/></div>";
            endif;
            $i++; //To prevent let's increase it
        }
        else ($date_start <= time()) {
            echo "<div class='aflyst_badge_normal'><img src='http://kursus.billetten.dk/wp-content/themes/kurser/img/afholdt.png' width=80/></div>";
        }
    }
```

**UPDATED** :

```
    $i=0; //For if statement
    $j=0; //For else statement
    foreach ($category_detail as $category_ID)
        {       
            if($category_ID->cat_name == 'z_aflyst') {
            if($i == 0):
                echo "<div class='aflyst_badge_normal'><img src='http://kursus.billetten.dk/wp-content/themes/kurser/img/aflyst.png' width=80/></div>";
            endif;
            $i++;
        }
        else ($date_start <= time()) {
            if($j == 0):
                echo "<div class='aflyst_badge_normal'><img src='http://kursus.billetten.dk/wp-content/themes/kurser/img/afholdt.png' width=80/></div>";
            endif;
            $j++;
        }
    }
```

**NOTE:** `UNTESTED`

Comment: Yours results in the exact same as what I was already getting.

Comment: Logically it should not ..Can you please play around it with bit ?It should echo only one time when `z_aflyst` is there. Why is it printing more than once ? Are you sure it is printing two times when `z_aflyst` is there ?

Comment: Thanks downvoter for not helping others and only giving downvotes.

Comment: if ($var == 0) without quotes, is it numeric, not text :)

Comment: I have just tried the updated code, that one works, but it also shows both the aflyst and afholdt banners when both are true (category `z_aflyst` is true and `<= time()` is true)

Comment: I am sorry but can you please tell me the use of `else ($date_start <= time())` in your code ? Is it really needed ? Can't we just put `else` only ?

Comment: No, just putting else would run every time a course doesn't have `z_aflyst`, while it of course happens that a course gets planned in the future which shouldn't have the "course has been held"-banner. Thats why I HAVE to check if a course's start date is in the past.

Comment: It won't print every time as there is another condition in else statement.You can give it try by removing just for debugging purpose.Else what we can do is put that condition in `else if` and add blank `<div></div>` in `else` condition.Tell me what is it giving?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67221/discussion-between-rohil-phpbeginner-and-rvervuurt).

Comment: I added a course in the future, a course that has been held in the past and a course that has been canceled. The canceled course shows both the "held" and "canceled" banners.
I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Based on:

```
foreach ($category_detail as $category_ID)
    {       
        if($category_ID->cat_name == 'z_aflyst') {
        echo "<div class='aflyst_badge_normal'><img src='http://kursus.billetten.dk/wp-content/themes/kurser/img/aflyst.png' width=80/></div>";
    }
    else ($date_start <= time()) {
        echo "<div class='aflyst_badge_normal'><img src='http://kursus.billetten.dk/wp-content/themes/kurser/img/afholdt.png' width=80/></div>";
    }
}
```

Let's create two var:

```
$z_aflyst= false;
$afholdt= false;
```

then let's see the loop

```
foreach ($category_detail as $category_ID)
    {
```

Let's change the IF

```
if($category_ID->cat_name == 'z_aflyst' && !$z_aflyst) {
     echo "<div class='aflyst_badge_normal'><img src='http://kursus.billetten.dk/wp-content/themes/kurser/img/aflyst.png' width=80/></div>";
     $z_aflyst = true;
}
else if($date_start <= time() && !$z_aflyst && !$afholdt) {
    echo "<div class='aflyst_badge_normal'><img src='http://kursus.billetten.dk/wp-content/themes/kurser/img/afholdt.png' width=80/></div>";
    $afholdt = true;
}
}
```

This code will print only 1 banner of each type.
If printed a z_aflyst it will not print afholdt
If printed a z_aflyst it will not print other z_aflyst
If printer a afholdt it will not print other afholdt

Is this what you needed?

Comment: Can it be the if/else doesn't work when `else` isn't `elseif`?

Comment: This solution is still producing a double banner when in the past AND canceled: http://i61.tinypic.com/sg04ty.png, otherwise it seems to do what I need! :)

Comment: o_o when in the past and already printed a z_etc it will not print thanks to the condition after the time && !$z_aflyst && !$afholdt